# Would Chlorine or Chloramine gas show up on a VOC test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

Would Chlorine or Chloramine gas show up on a VOC test?  My apartment was cleaned using chlorox and lysol, and there has been a smell that's been lingering for about 10 days.  The air was tested with a VOC meter but nothing came up.  Would Chlorine and Chloramine have shown up on this test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chlorine, no. Chloramine, maybe.

Monochloramine, $\ce{NH2Cl}$, is an inorganic compound, and not very volatile (when dissolved in water it forms more or less of an azeotrope, evaporating slightly faster than the water itself). So, not a VOC.

However, the way it does its job as a disinfectant is to basically shred organic compounds, like cell walls, key enzymes, etc, forming "organic chloramines" where one or more of the remaining hydrogens is replaced with an organic functional group. These now-organic compounds have a higher vapor pressure, so by design, chloramine is used to *create* VOCs. The idea, when used in tap water or pool/spa chlorination, is to allow the organic chloramines to boil off and disperse in the air, leaving clean water behind. That "chlorine smell" of a chlorinated pool is actually mostly organic chloramines evaporating out. In a more enclosed space like an interior room, these compounds can't disperse and so the smell builds.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. What are some definite ways to test for Chlorine and Chloramine in the air?